# Excel add one month to a date ensuring it does not fall on a weekend

Tags: excel

I have some workday in cell `A1`, say 25/07/2013. I add one month using the formula 
`edate(A1,1)`, returning 25/08/2013 which is a weekend. How do I ensure that the next business day is returned instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check out this link: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/workday-HP005209339.aspx on the function `WORKDAY` which will return the next-n-working day.
It's tempting to do `Workday(A1,0)` to find the next working day after date specified in A1, but it's not doing the job.

So we need to do this trick:

```
=Workday( edate(A1,1)-1 , 1 )
```

the result is a number representing the serial number of the next working day.
The trick is you consider the previous day, then find the next working day after it. So if the date is a working day, it will return it, while if it is not a working day, it will return the next one.

I hope Microsoft modifies this method, though, so that when you enter workday(A1,0) it will return the next working day automatically.

So for example you want to find the next working day one month after 27-Jun-2013 (which would be 27-Jun-2013, but that's Saturday, so it should return 29-Jun-2013 instead):

```
=Workday( edate(date(2013,6,27),1)-1 , 1 )
```

will return you `40022`, which refers to the date 29-Jul-2013, which is the next working day.

To get the formatted result as 29-Jul-2013, you need to format your cell with `Format->Cell->Date`

Answer (score 1):

shortest formula I can find : 
    =WORKDAY(WORKDAY(edate(A1,1),-1),1)